# Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in on line 44

Tags: php

HTML code for the search engine which I believe is correct
    
    
     Search

## My Search Engine

> PHP code starts here where I believe the error is coming from

```
if(!$button)
echo "you didn't submit a keyword"; else
{
if(strlen($search)<=1)
echo "Search term too short";
else{
echo "You searched for <b>$search</b> <hr size='1'></br>";
mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
mysql_select_db("testproject");

$search_exploded = explode (" ", $search);
foreach($search_exploded as $search_each)
{
$x = NULL; $construct = NULL;
$x++;
if($x==1)
$construct .="keywords LIKE '%$search_each%'";
else
$construct .="AND keywords LIKE '%$search_each%'";
}
$construct ="SELECT * FROM members WHERE $construct";
$run = mysql_query($construct);

$foundnum = mysql_num_rows($run);
if ($foundnum==0)
echo "Sorry, there are no matching result for <b>$search</b>.
</br></br>1. Try more general words.";
else
{
echo "$foundnum results found !<p>";

while($runrows = mysql_fetch_assoc($run))
{
$username = $runrows ['username'];
$email = $runrows ['email'];

} 
}
}
}
?>
```

keep getting: Warning: mysql_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in

Comment: **warning** your code is vulnerable to sql injection attacks!

Answer (score 1):

I think this is just a space problem in your query, just try to add spaces like

```
$construct .=" AND keywords LIKE '%$search_each%'";
```

Also note that `keyword` should be the name of table's column where you want to look for.

I would like to also to remember you that `mysql_` functions are deprecated so i would advise you to switch to [`mysqli`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) or [`PDO`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) and indeed you are at risk of sql injection

Comment: This is what comes back:You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'AND keywords LIKE '%

Comment: Try to print your query to see how it looks like. I would suggest to change your query in `$construct_query = "SELECT * FROM members WHERE $construct"; echo $construct_query; $run = mysql_query($construct_query);`

Answer (score 0):

That's probably because the SQL request failed. Try to append `or die(mysql_error())` next to `$run = mysql_query($construct)`, like this :

```
$run = mysql_query($construct) or die(mysql_error());
```

This should output the error so that you can fix it.

Answer (score 0):

Probably, there is an error in the query. Try this:

```
$run = mysql_query($construct);
if (!$run)
  echo 'an error occurred: '.mysql_error();
else {
  $foundnum = mysql_num_rows($run);
  if ($foundnum==0)
  echo "Sorry, there are no matching result for <b>$search</b>.
  </br></br>1. Try more general words.";
else {
  echo "$foundnum results found !<p>"; 
  while($runrows = mysql_fetch_assoc($run)) {
    $username = $runrows ['username'];
    $email = $runrows ['email']; 
  } 
}
```

This script will tell you what the problem is. As Fabio writes, you'll probably see get the MySQL reported starting at the point where a space is expected. (You might need to add some br tags in this example if you want to use it on your website.)